# .htaccess rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this .htaccess that I've been using to rewrite URLs like these:

```
www.example.com/index.php?page=brand          www.example.com/brand
www.example.com/index.php?page=contact        www.example.com/contact
www.example.com/index.php?page=giveaways      www.example.com/giveaways
```

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I used a file called index.php to handle the redirects. Code used below:

```
$page = trim($_GET['page']);
if($page == "giveaways")
    require('pages/giveaways.php');
```

Now, I would like to add another URL type like these:

```
www.example.com/index.php?page=products&p=ford-mustang
```

TO

```
www.example.com/products/ford-mustang
```

How will I accomplish this? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ok, pls edit question for removing downvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a second RewriteRule above your current one.
Here's an example:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA]
```

This will rewrite `/product/ford-mustang` to `index.php?page=product&p=ford-mustang`

Remember to add it above your current RewriteRule, because it first tries to match the first RewriteRule, when there's no match it will go on with the second RewriteRule and so further.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!


I used this code:

`RewriteEngine on`

`RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

`RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA]`

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]`

The result is somehow okay but my CSS is not working. What could be caused this problem?

Comment: if your CSS is in a folder, you can add a rule to ignore it...   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css\.* [NC]
would ignore everyting in http://www.domain.com/css add this BEFORE the RewriteRule

Comment: That's because the path to your css file is relative, something like this: `stylesheets/style.css`, then when you have such RewriteRule, the browser tries to include this file: `/product/ford-mustang/stylesheets/style.css`. That file doesn't exists.
Try to use absolute paths (like this: `http://website.com/stylesheets/style.css`) or make it relative to your domain (like this: `/stylesheets/style.css`, notice the leading slash).

Comment: @Ray I've used absolute path like http://example.com/css/template.css but the CSS file still won't work.

Comment: @Brian. I used RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css\.* [NC] but still won't work.

Comment: Strange, do you have a live example?

Comment: Ah, your css is in a subfolder with the same structure as your url. Add `|css` to your first RewriteCond.

Comment: @acidpaul let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/971/discussion-between-ray-and-acidpaul)

Answer (score 2):

A URL rewrite for `/products/ford-mustang` would be:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA]`